# How do you convert URL to NSString when you get error: Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsstring, firebase-storage

I had code that was too old for pod updates with metadata:

```
 let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef.key!)
        let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef1.key!)


        newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
            self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            newPostRef.setValue(self.imageDownloadURL as Any)


        })



        newImageRef1.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
            self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

            let keyToPost = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).childByAutoId().key
            let f1: [String: Any] = [(keyToPost) : self.imageDownloadURL as Any]

            newPostRef1.updateChildValues(f1)

                           })
```

Someone suggested the following fix, but it produces an error: Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary. Now I plan to change the set value and update child values to an NSString.

```
 newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
              newImageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                  return
                }
                newPostRef.setValue(url)
              }
            })



            newImageRef1.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                                                    newImageRef1.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                                                      guard let downloadURL = url else {
                                                        return
                                                      }
                                                      let keyToPost = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).childByAutoId().key ?? "I am a default value"
                                                      let f1: [String: Any] = [(keyToPost) : newImageRef1.downloadURL as Any]

                                                      newPostRef1.updateChildValues(f1)
                                                    }
                                                  })
```

Comment: You can get a String representation of an URL instance by accessing it's `.absoluteString` property.

Comment: @Gamma so basically just add .absoluteString to url in newPostRef.setValue(url)?

Comment: Yes. If you compare your "old" version with the "new" one, note that you were previously also not setting URLs directly, but instead used those URLs `absoluteString`s. You still need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the APi documentation for [downloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRStorageReference(im)downloadURLWithCompletion:) that it yields a [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) object.  That has an [absoluteString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779984-absolutestring) property that you can add to Firebase.

```
let f1: [String: Any] = [
    (keyToPost) : downloadURL.absoluteString
]
```